# Regex not working with group in group

Tags: python, regex

I'm wondering why my regex is not working. The only group it works on is year.
The rest of the groups are None.

```
formatted_date = re.search('.*((?P<day>\d{1,2}) )?((?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+) )?(?P<year>\d{4}).*', '10 may 1991')
```

The idea behind the regex is that it will work on the following input:

- 10 may 1991
- may 1991
- 1991

The regex is written in Python.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use lazy matching with the dot at the start: `.*?`, but I do not think you even need it.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor!!! I will never forget about lazy matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that greedy dot matching subpattern at the beginning of the pattern grabs all the characters up to the end, and then backtracks yielding what it has to yield to accommodate for the other subpatterns. Since the first 2 are optional, no text is given to them.

You do not need any `.*` as `re.search` does not require a full string match.

Use

```
(?:(?P<day>\d{1,2}) )?(?:(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+) )?(?P<year>\d{4})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dY9hE1/2)

I also converted capturing optional groups to non-capturing so that the match object was a bit cleaner.

Note that if you still use your approach, you might consider using `.*?` at the beginning of the pattern (lazy dot matching), but you would have to worry about newlines then (ok, you can use `re.S` flag to solve that one), and that way, you'd get the *first* instance of the date in your string. If you have more than one, and you need to get the last one, the best approach is to use `re.findall` with my suggested pattern and just get the last element of the resulting list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regex makes a lot more sense to me now. Best answer I could hope for :)